# How to make this context free grammar unambiguous?

Tags: algorithm, context-free-grammar, ambiguous, formal-languages, context-free-language

The language is all binary strings of the form `(0^i)(1^j) where 2i >= j`. In other words, the set of binary strings where there is at most twice as many `1's` then `0's` and all the `0's` are leading.

**My attempt:**

```
S -> 0S | T

T -> 0T1 | U

U -> 0U11 | epsilon
```

However, this is ambiguous on the `string 0011`. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Uh...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin) Are you sure SO is the correct site to post this?

Comment: @user202729 [Questions about algorithms are *explicitly* on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it, just one small change:

```
S -> 0S | T    
T -> 0U1 | U 
U -> 0U11 | epsilon
```

This makes sure that a certain number of 1s can only be produced in exactly one way. The rule  S -> 0S is then used to produce the still necessary 0s.